# spring data jpa transaction not rollbacking

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I am Using Spring Data Jpa and adding inserting into 2 table when  something happen while adding into second table the first transaction is not rollbacking
and first insert is **commiting immidiatally** after insert

```
 @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = 
  Exception.class)
    public void addVehicleType(Map<String, Object> model)throws Exception {
        VehicleType     vehicleType     = null;
        VehicleStatus   vehicleStatus   = null;
        try {
            vehicleType         = (VehicleType) model.get("vehicleType");
            vehicleStatus       = (VehicleStatus) model.get("vehicleStatus");

            vehicleStatusRepository.save(vehicleStatus);

            vehicleTypeRepository.save(vehicleType);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
```

VehicleTypeRepository.java

```
public interface VehicleTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<VehicleType, Long> {


    @Override
    void delete(VehicleType role);

    long count();
}
```

Comment: How do your repositories look like?

Comment: public interface VehicleTypeRepository extends JpaRepository<VehicleType, Long> {

 
 @Override
 void delete(VehicleType role);

 long count();
}

Comment: are you using spring boot?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes i am using spring boot

Comment: Manish, can you show me the classes hierarchy util the method addVehicleType() call? For example: ManagedBean A -> bean spring service B1 -> bean spring service B2 -> bean spring B3 -> method() with annotation. On this case the @Transactional annotation must be on bean spring B1 instead on bean spring B3.

Comment: I have same issue in informix db please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use mysql, you must have InnoDB Engine. 
Second, problem could be if you are testing on local pc.
Uncomment in my.ini default_tmp_storage_engine=MYISAM
; The default storage engine that will be used when create new tables
; default-storage-engine=MYISAM
; New for MySQL 5.6 default_tmp_storage_engine if skip-innodb enable
default_tmp_storage_engine=MYISAM

Comment: you are right it was issue with storage engine after alter table engine to innodb and editing dialect property to MySQLInnoDBDialect it is working now

Answer (score 0):

The only exceptions that set a transaction to rollback state by default are the unchecked exceptions (like RuntimeException).

Please note that the Spring Framework's transaction infrastructure code will, by default, only mark a transaction for rollback in the case of runtime, unchecked exceptions; that is, when the thrown exception is an instance or subclass of RuntimeException. (Errors will also - by default - result in a rollback.) Checked exceptions that are thrown from a transactional method will not result in the transaction being rolled back.